# Losing Redux state between page transitions Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, redux-toolkit, redux-persist

I have introduced `redux-persist` in my app and starts losing Redux state on the page transition. I believe this is hydration problem but not sure how to solve it.
here is my store

```
export function createPersistStorage(): WebStorage {
  const isServer = typeof window === 'undefined'

  // Returns noop (dummy) storage.
  if (isServer) {
    return {
      getItem() {
        return Promise.resolve(null)
      },
      setItem() {
        return Promise.resolve()
      },
      removeItem() {
        return Promise.resolve()
      }
    }
  }

  return createWebStorage('local')
}

const storage = typeof window !== 'undefined' ? createWebStorage('local') : createPersistStorage()

const reducer = combineReducers({
  [hubSlice.name]: hubSlice.reducer,
  [api.reducerPath]: api.reducer
})

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'primary',
  storage,
  whitelist: ['hub']
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducer)

export const makeStore = () =>
  configureStore({
    reducer: persistedReducer,
    middleware: (gDM) => gDM({ serializableCheck: false }).concat(api.middleware)
  })

type AppStore = ReturnType<typeof makeStore>
export type AppState = ReturnType<AppStore['getState']>

export type AppDispatch = AppStore['dispatch']

export type AppThunk<ReturnType = void> = ThunkAction<ReturnType, AppState, unknown, AnyAction>
```

Here is my `_app.tsx`

```
const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) => {
  const store = makeStore()
  const persistor = persistStore(store, {}, function () {
    persistor.persist()
  })
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <CssBaseline />

        <ThemeProvider theme={staplesTheme}>
          <SnackbarProvider autoHideDuration={6000} preventDuplicate>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </SnackbarProvider>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

here is how I use `Link` Next.js component

```
<Link href={`/planning/${item.id}`} style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: 'black' }}>
          <OpenInNewIcon sx={{ marginRight: 0.5, cursor: 'pointer' }} />
        </Link>
```

I am using `redux/toolkit`

Comment: Your server "persistence" does nothing. What is your intention of including empty server storage, rather than using the default localStorage mechanism client side only of redux-perist? If you're seeing data disappear between page loads that could be why. Also what is the definition of `createWebStorage`? If it's not using `storage` from the library then it might not be getting saved anywhere. You can also check what's in localStorage with the normal browser API at each page load.

Comment: @AndyRay I was experiencing a problem when on server side localStorage was unavailable here is link https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/15687

Comment: I see that when I navigate to other page my app is rebuilding. At this moment I lose my Redux state. Again I am using Next.js